# What's a word that can mean both "good" and "bad"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, slang

I've recently read about a word that was defined both as "shockingly good" and "shockingly bad", but I can't seem to recall the word. Does anyone know what it is? As far as I can recall, it was a slang word.

**Edit:** I hate to answer my own question, but I just found the word again, it's *egregious*, defined [here](http://www.google.ro/search?q=define%3aegregious).

Comment: Why not *shocking*?

Comment: *sick* added by @Robusto works. Why does this question get voted down?!

Comment: This question seems a fair word request to me.

Comment: 'Bad' is the classic example of this: e.g. "That's one bad cat" can be negative or positive.

Comment: Good one: egregious. But, I should caution you it is not slang, quite a formal word it is. Though, it is used more in the negative sense, than the good.

Comment: Since the question is closed (unjustifiably, IMHO), I have to put my answer as a comment: The word “interesting”, spoken slowly, is deliciously ambivalent.

Comment: Outrageous! (Question should not have been closed, imo.)

Comment: @Mitch -- your answer is the baddest! Wish I'd thought of it.

Comment: @karthik: I've never heard 'egregious' in a positive setting. Do you have an example?

Comment: This question is just *terrible*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colloquial expression *sick* covers both of those bases.

Comment: This, along with Mitch's reply, is closest to what I was originally looking for. Thanks!

Comment: 'sick' is more extreme, in the direction of 'shockingly'. But for both, the positive version is usually slang and needs the right situation.

Comment: What about "outrageous" and "mad"?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what term you may be referring to, but bear in mind that irony can always turn anything to mean its opposite.

> You passed your mid term exams? **Good** ! What's next? The finals?
>   You killed your cat? **Good** ! What's next? Your parents?

Comment: Michael Jackson introduced "Bad" as having the meaning of "Good" to the mainstream a few centuries ago. "Can there be no end to this confusion??" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've heard "awesome"? It literally means something that creates fear, but it's used in colloquial situations to express that something is "great", "fantastic" or "cool".

Comment: Any reason why my answer isn't helpful?

Comment: I can't think of any context in which "awesome" would mean "shockingly bad" as in the question. Moreover awe is a specific concept, although it could be related to some kind of fear. Like in the *sublime*

Comment: 'Awesome' has changed its meaning over time. The OP is asking about a word right now that can be used for one meaning and its opposite.

Comment: @Mitch: Well, *awesome* is definitely no worse than *egregious*, which **right now** only means extremely bad (and I honestly never knew it to mean anything else). At least *awesome* still, to this day, really means "evoking awe", which can be either positive, negative, or (most properly) a mingling of both.

Comment: @JohnY: OK. 'awesome' I suppose could be used for something negative, it's just not the first thing that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The question is an interesting one.
If it is about feelings for a thing or person, a formal option could be "ambivalent", if it is supposed to evoke both good and bad reactions / love and  hate emotions about a thing or a person.

Another interesting case could be a word, that can be interpreted to be either good or bad, and the person who used the term meant only one of those, not both. Such a word is "fantastic" and also a reason @Raku should not have used it in his answer. If I say, "John gave us fantastic support at the time of crisis", I may have meant it in a good way, that his support was really something beyond what could be expected, or in a bad way, I may have meant that his support was not of any worth, it was unreal, imaginary, fantastic. 
There are similar other words, which you can think of.

Comment: I was referring more to what you meant in your second paragraph. Thank you!