# A word that describes a process that can be both good and bad

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am searching for a word that can describe an object or process as having both bad and good elements.

I realize this is a repeat of [this previous question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58026/whats-a-word-that-can-mean-both-good-and-bad), but I do not believe the suggestions answer my question;

- ***Egregious***, the proposed answer by the OP, is not a common enough word (anyone I have asked has had to look it up), nor does it mean precisely what I'm after,
- ***Sick*** is a word that can be used in both good and bad contexts. It does not actually mean "both good and bad".

The context I am working is biological, specifically cognitive impairment (such as dementia). In a publication I am working on currently, I would like to describe the role of inflammation as having both good and bad roles (depending on the situation).

I can think of possible sayings that might apply, for example "swings and roundabouts" or "bitter-sweet", but again these do not seem formal enough.

Is there a word that fits the context? "Inflammation is a double-edged sword..." but more scientifically!

Comment: I think you should forgo the hunt for a single word and simply say, "Inflammation has both beneficial and detrimental effects ..." or something along those lines.

Comment: I was going to suggest "Sword of Damocles" but I see you already considered and discarded "double-edged sword."

Comment: What Jim said, except that I think "double-edged sword" would suffice in all but the most stuffy of scientific contexts :)

Comment: "A mixed blessing".

Comment: @Jim that is of course a possibility. I was just sure that I'd heard a word used that quite accurately represented my meaning! Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Comment: For that matter, there is the word `bad` itself.

Comment: @T.E.D. the word 'bad' can mean bad OR good - I could surely not use it in this context to mean both!

Comment: @Lynn I agree, and they would have to be very stuffy indeed: searching Google Scholar for ["double-edged sword"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22double+edged+sword%22) returns 84,000 articles, the very first of which is from the prestigious journal *Science*.

Comment: Feh. I use the word "egregious" all the time.

Comment: But "egregious" means "incredibly bad". It does not at all mean "can be either good or bad".

Comment: "Sick" does not mean "good or bad" either, but just "bad".

Comment: @Lynn - Much more formal and less offensive than "bitch-goddess", which otherwise might have the intended meaning.

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to find a good scientific term. Science doesn't generally concern itself with such things as "good" and "bad".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about **[dualistic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dualism)**?

As in the Oxford Dictionary:

> Theology .
>
> a.
>   the doctrine that there are two independent divine beings or eternal principles, one good and the other evil.

Seems appropriate to say that inflammation has a dualistic role.

Comment: As the definition you quote indicates, "dualism" is a theory in theology. It is unlikely that the original poster wants to say that inflammation causes or is caused by competing good and evil spirits.

Comment: @Jay while you have a point, the definition of the word is not confined to the domain of theology.

Comment: I think this may be the easiest to immediately interpret what I'm getting at. I will obviously need to explain the concepts I'm talking about initially, but to refer back to the "dualistic nature of the inflammatory response" would work very well indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @Luke glad to be of help although to be honest I'm surprised that you would call my answer the best. English isn't even my native language and I don't study it or anything. Personally I think you should seriously consider `ambivalent` and `bipolar`.

Comment: Well, it's true that the term is also used in philosophy with a slightly different meaning. But still, to the best of my knowledge, this term is very specific. It does not refer to anything that could have pros and cons, but to a theory that the universe has a "split personality".

Comment: @Mario: I'd use _dualistic_ before _ambivalent_ or _bipolar_. Maybe it needs to be used with a little bit of caution, but I think you've made a good suggestion. Don't sell yourself short.

Comment: I agree with @J.R. - you have made a good suggestion! Dualistic is a term I could comfortably use to refer back to the "dualistic nature of the immune system" without any qualms about the reader missing my point due to an unfamiliar word. I will wait to see any more suggestions, but otherwise this would be my first choice I think.

Answer (score 10):

How about *agathocacological*?

*agathoˌkakoˈlogical, adj.
Etymology:  < Greek ἀγαθό-ς good + κακό-ς bad + -logical comb. form.
nonce-wd.*

*Composed of good and evil.*

or from WordNik [agathocacological](http://www.wordnik.com/words/agathocacological)

Comment: That's an amazing word; I have full intentions of ostracizing myself with its continuous usage.

Comment: Yes, I liked it, and it sounds very scientific as the OP requested. I must crowbar it into a conversation sometime tomorrow.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps *[ambivalent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambivalent)* would be of some use; it seems like a reasonable extension of the second meaning:-

> Psychology . of or pertaining to the coexistence within an individual
>   of positive and negative feelings toward the same person, object, or
>   action, simultaneously drawing him or her in opposite directions.

**Edit** I've just noticed this was also suggested by Karthik at the previous question.

Comment: Ambivalent by its correct definition is perfect. Unfortunately, far too many English speakers (including native speakers) think it merely means "undecided" or "not caring one way or the other."

Comment: This is good. Along the same lines, **ambiguous** could also work - it is a little less correct than **ambivalent**, but it might be more likely to be understood on the first read.

Answer (score 5):

How about *[twofold](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/twofold)*:

> : having two parts or aspects

The idiom *[cuts both ways](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+both+ways)* may be a better fit:

> to have both advantages and disadvantages

Comment: An equivalent expression to the second idiom as a metaphor is "a double-edged sword". Usually this idiom or metaphor is used to describe something which would exhibit the good and bad simultaneously.

Comment: "Twofold" means a doubling, not one way and another.

Comment: The two aspects can differ.

Answer (score 5):

Consider [bipolar](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bipolar?q=bipolar)

> having or relating to two poles or extremities:
>
> *a sharply bipolar division of affluent and underclass*

While this is not limited to *good* and *bad*, it should be easy to construct a sentence that reflects the characteristic you are seeking

> *Inflammation can be bipolar in the effect it brings about on the [insert the process/function affected].*

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using a play on words, you could always consider using 'ambidextrous'.

While common definition is that one is good with both hands, (and I have the play here for you, will say later), there is another definition.

> characterized by duplicity

(As it had been stated by [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambidextrous?show=0&t=1347487465).)

The play here, as I mentioned earlier, is that the left hand often symbolizes the 'bad' and the right symbolizes the 'good'.

So one could say that:

> Inflammation can be ambidextrous with its roles.

Or rather:

> Inflammation is ambidextrous with its roles.

Hope that helps and not wasted time.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Duplicity ("double-dealing") isn't a bad suggestion either!

Comment: Hope it works for you! (I'm very happy I inserted the other meaning!) Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

How about 'mixed results'? That carries the meaning of 'good and bad'.

I also thought of 'multifarious'.

You could say 'inflammation has multifarious outcomes'. Or multifarious effects.

https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=meaning+multifarous&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-sg&client=safari

Though multifarious doesn't *specifically* contain 'positive and negative' - though it does mean 'varied' and that can include nonspecifically good and bad.

I did also find one alternative to 'double-edged sword', 
'Patchy' - meaning, varied results.

And I then lastly, thought of 'mixed results' which could do the job quite well - it is sufficiently formal, and carries the meaning of 'good and bad' - as well as 'various'.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be an adjective, I would say the most colloquial thing I can think of is referring to it as being "a mixed bag".

> Definition of mixed bag
>
> 1 : a miscellaneous collection : ASSORTMENT
>
> **2 : one having both positive and negative qualities or aspects**

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mixed%20bag

Answer (score -1):

What about 'Omen'? 'An event regarded as a portent of good or evil.' There are good and bad omens, so it may be a valid answer to this:)

Comment: Where is that quote from? Always indicate your sources.

Answer (score -4):

**Awesome**: usually used to mean 'impressive' but literally means awe inspiring. Both good and bad things can be awesome, (at the extremity of their category.)

Comment: Something can be "awesomely good" or it could be "awesomely bad", but that doesn't mean that "awesome" by itself means that it can be both. It's like saying "very".

Comment: "I saw Gods power and it was awesome" "The devils works are awesome".  "awesomely good" is a tautology.

Comment: @Jay 's point is that "awesome" does not answer the question. The OP wants a word that specifically connotes "both good and bad". "Awesome" does not specifically connote "both good and bad"; it has a different meaning (impressive or awe inspiring) that does not have the requested connotation.