# Word meaning a group of things contains both good and bad.

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if you had a bunch of strangers baking cookies, you might say

> The cookies produced were [adjective].

Meaning there were both good and bad results in the set.

Or:

> Jean went out in a tight fitting short skirt. The reactions she got were [adjective].

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81170/a-word-that-describes-a-process-that-can-be-both-good-and-bad

Comment: A colloquial phrase, rather than a word, would be 'hit and miss'

Answer (score 10):

I think [contrasting](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/contrasting) ( also *conflicting*)  can fit in your second example:

> - different, especially with strong dissimilarities , between entities or objects compared.

or [mixed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Mixed):

> - Composed of a variety of differing, sometimes conflicting entities: viewed the change in management with mixed emotions; a closet full of mixed outfits.

As for the biscuits I think you have to be more specific saying 'that they were not all good'.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: Mmm, I think I'm wanting to highlight the bad in the set.

Comment: @dwjohnston - you are asking for a mix of good and bad in your question. You should be more specific in your request if you want to stress one aspect (bad) vs the other ( good).

Comment: Yeah, I'm being difficult. The answer given certainly fits the question posed. :)

Answer (score 4):

I know "mixed" was given above, but I don't think it's as accurate as

> **mixed bag**
>   (idiomatic) something tending to have both good and bad results or characteristics; something having a mixture of advantages and disadvantages.

*The results of the cookie competition were a mixed bag.*

Source : http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/mixed_bag

Answer (score 0):

Although **so-so** means neither very good nor very bad, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so-so), it seemingly fits your tone and content, in that none were outstanding in any way. You could say *[ranged](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ranged)* but you'd sound like a stiff using it as a single word.

> The cookies produced were *so-so*.

The cliche, "**varied** reactions":

> Jean received *varied* reactions when she went out in a tight fitting short skirt.

She also got "*[assorted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assorted)* looks".

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to highlight the bad, then a good expression would be a "[curate's egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curate's_egg)" as in, "*the results were a bit of a curate's egg*" :

The expression itself comes from an old Punch cartoon caption;

> **Bishop:** *"I'm afraid you've got a bad egg, Mr Jones"*
>   **Curate:** *"Oh, no, my Lord, I assure you that parts of it are excellent!"*

[image]
**"True Humility" by George du Maurier, originally published in Punch, 9 November 1895.**

Comment: That's a great phrase, but I don't think most Americans would recognize it. It might be a strictly a UKism.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use, *poise, equipoise, equilibrium,* or *stasis*. They all have the same definition:
A condition in which opposing forces are equal to one another.

If you're sneaky, you could use *aplomb*, which means:
Evenness of emotions or temper.

*Antipodal* and *diametric* mean:
Being as different as possible.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).